# Sum mysql only works for the first row or just get wrong

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got this:

```
SELECT `cuenta`.`reservaId`, sum(`cuenta`.`tarifaTotal`)
FROM `check`,`cuenta`,`comanda`,`reserva`
WHERE `comanda`.`id`=`cuenta`.`idComanda` AND `comanda`.`tipo`=0
GROUP BY `cuenta`.`reservaId` ORDER BY `check`.`id`
```

the problem is that I get something like 10000000 as result of the first "reservaID" over the 119 I should get.

When I use this code, it works, but Only for the first "reservaID" space:

```
SELECT `cuenta`.`reservaId`, sum(`cuenta`.`tarifaTotal`)
FROM `check`,`reserva`,`cuenta`,`comanda`
WHERE `cuenta`.`reservaId`=`reserva`.`id` AND `cuenta`.`idComanda`=`comanda`.`id` AND `check`.`idReserva`=`reserva`.`id` AND `comanda`.`tipo`=0
GROUP BY `cuenta`.`reservaId`
ORDER BY `check`.`id`
```

tables:
check: id, reservaID
reserva: id, idPersona, idEmpresa, etc.
cuenta: reservaID, idComanda, Tarifatotal(this field is like mini bills, so "tarifatotal" is the price for each mini-bill)
comanda: id, name, tipo(or type, who can be 0,1,2 or 3) to describe the service type, like drinks, restaurant, services, others

Please help, I want to show all "sum"s for every single "reservaID".

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT cuenta.reservaId, sum(cuenta.tarifaTotal) FROM check 
JOIN reserva
ON reserva.id = check.idReserva
JOIN cuenta
ON cuenta.reservaId = reserva.id
JOIN comanda 
ON comanda.id = cuenta.idComanda
WHERE comanda.tipo = 0
GROUP BY cuenta.reservaId
ORDER BY check.id;
```

Comment: only works for the first ID, in the table cuenta are many IDs, but I only get the SUM for the first one

Comment: thank you, at the end it works, I just had to restart my pc

Comment: I'm glad it helped, weird stuff going on xD

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a `left join` would solve your problems:

```
SELECT r.id, sum(c.tarifaTotal)
FROM reserva r LEFT JOIN
     cuenta c
     ON c.reservaId = r.id LEFT JOIN
     commanda co
     ON co.id = c.idCommanda
WHERE co.tipo = 0
GROUP BY r.id;
```

You don't seem to need the `check` table.  Your `ORDER BY` doesn't make sense, because `check.id` is not in the `SELECT` list or `GROUP BY` list.

Comment: this code is similar to the second one of mine, I understand how you changed WHEREs for JOINs in the code, and it works. But as mine, only works for the first "reservaID" or "r.id"

Comment: @FeberCastellon . . . I don't get the point of your comment.  This code is quite different from anything in your question, both syntactically and semantically.